# Android Jetpack compose, field expose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a question about this code,

```
    private val _removingPluggableScreens = mutableStateOf(false)
    val removingPluggableScreens: Boolean get() = _removingPluggableScreens.value

    fun updateRemovingPluggableScreens(shouldRemovePluggableScreens: Boolean) {
        if (shouldRemovePluggableScreens != _removingPluggableScreens.value) {
            _removingPluggableScreens.value = shouldRemovePluggableScreens
        }
    }
```

The code is working fine as expected, but if I change the code this way-- without get() for removingPluggableScreens field it does not work as expected,

```
    private val _removingPluggableScreens = mutableStateOf(false)
    val removingPluggableScreens: Boolean = _removingPluggableScreens.value

    fun updateRemovingPluggableScreens(shouldRemovePluggableScreens: Boolean) {
        if (shouldRemovePluggableScreens != _removingPluggableScreens.value) {
            _removingPluggableScreens.value = shouldRemovePluggableScreens
        }
    }
```

When I observe the state like this, it's not working correctly if I choose the second approach, but it works fine if I choose the first approach:

```
    val removingPluggableScreens = viewModel.removingPluggableScreens  
    if (removingPluggableScreens) {
        // do sth here
    }
```

Simply, I want to know the differences between `val removingPluggableScreens: Boolean get() = _removingPluggableScreens.value` and `val removingPluggableScreens: Boolean = _removingPluggableScreens.value`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to a variable, this happens only once, in your case, when you declare it. And in the future, these 2 variables in your code are not related in any way.

When you specify a getter, When you specify a getter, it is called every time the value of the `removingPluggableScreens` is read. And in your case this value will always match the `_removingPluggableScreens.value`.